# Better to use a DataMart (BI) or scheduled view to capture rapidly-changing attribute (status)?

Tags: sql, database, datamart

Currently we depend on OLTP system to develop reports. Basically, We want to track the sales campaign. So, we need to see the total amount of sales at sales stages of 'Opportunity', 'Proposal', 'Contract Sent' for example. And needless to say that in the OLTP, each record has one current status (sales stage) that changes. For analytical reporting we need to consider historical data and perform aggregate operations on.

So, which is best: to capture this via a view that is scheduled daily to copy all sales orders (along with their sales status), or to design a small Data Mart solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a data mart, but the answer mostly depends on whether or not you want to track any of this information over time. If all you care about is analyzing the daily information in isolation as a one-off, skip the data mart. If you want to see how deals are trending and compare quantity of sales at various stages in the pipeline and see how these things change over time, go with the data mart.

Note that with the data mart approach, you'll probably build an ETL (extract, transform, and load) process that does something similar to your daily view snapshot to get the data out of the OLTP system.